# How can I do assignments in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to use the assignment operator in a list comprehension. How can I do that?

The following code is invalid syntax. I mean to set `lst[0]` to an empty string `''` if it matches `pattern`:

```
[ lst[0] = '' for pattern in start_pattern if lst[0] == pattern ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 103):

Python 3.8 will introduce [**Assignment Expressions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

It is a new symbol: `:=` that allows assignment in (among other things) comprehensions. This new operator is also known as **the walrus operator**.

It will introduce a lot of potential savings w.r.t. computation/memory, as can be seen from the following snippet of the above linked PEP (formatting adapted for SO):

> ### Syntax and semantics
>
> In most contexts where arbitrary Python expressions can be used, a
>   named expression can appear. This is of the form `NAME := expr` where
>   `expr` is any valid Python expression other than an unparenthesized
>   tuple, and `NAME` is an identifier.
>
> The value of such a named expression is the same as the incorporated
>   expression, with the additional side-effect that the target is
>   assigned that value:
>
> 1. **Handle a matched regex**
>
>    ```
>    if (match := pattern.search(data)) is not None:
>        # Do something with match
>    ```
> 2. **A loop that can't be trivially rewritten using 2-arg iter()**
>
>    ```
>    while chunk := file.read(8192):
>        process(chunk)
>    ```
> 3. **Reuse a value that's expensive to compute**
>
>    ```
>    [y := f(x), y**2, y**3]
>    ```
> 4. **Share a subexpression between a comprehension filter clause and its output**
>
>    ```
>    filtered_data = [y for x in data if (y := f(x)) is not None]
>    ```

This is already available in the recently releases alpha version (not recommended for production systems!). You can find [the release schedule for Python 3.8 here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0569/#id6).

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot assign to an expression using a subscript. `a[i] := 'foo'` will throw an exception: `SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with subscript`

Comment: isn't `None` falsey in python? ie: is the `is not None` necessary, and if so, when?

Comment: @CervEd when asserting that a value is not None, or more expressively, when trying to determine that an object has a value different than None.

Answer (score 37):

It looks like you are confusing [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [looping constructs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) in Python.

A list comprehension produces -- a list! It does not lend itself to a single assignment in an existing list. (Although you can torture the syntax to do that...)

While it isn't exactly clear what you are trying to do from your code, I think it is more similar to looping over the list (flow control) vs producing a list (list comprehension)

Loop over the list like this:

```
for pattern in patterns:
   if lst[0] == pattern: lst[0]=''
```

That is a reasonable way to do this, and is what you would do in C, Pascal, etc. But you can also just test the list for the one value and change it:

```
if lst[0] in patterns: lst[0] = ''
```

Or, if you don't know the index:

```
i=lst.index[pattern]
lst[i]=''
```

or, if you have a list of lists and want to change each first element of each sublist:

```
for i, sublst in enumerate(lst):
    if sublst[i][0] in patterns: sublist[i][0]=''
```

etc, etc, etc.

If you want to apply something to each element of a list, then you can look at using a list comprehension, or map, or one of the many other tools in the Python kit.

Personally, I usually tend to use list comprehensions more for list creation:

```
 l=[[ x for x in range(5) ] for y in range(4)]  #init a list of lists...
```

Which is more natural than:

```
l=[]
for i in range(4):
   l.append([])
   for j in range(5):
      l[i].append(j)
```

But to modify that same list of lists, which is more understandable?

This:

```
l=[['new value' if j==0 else l[i][j] for j in range(len(l[i]))] for i in range(len(l))]
```

or this:

```
for i,outter in enumerate(l):
    l[i][0]='new value'
```

YMMV

[Here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) is a great tutorial on this.

Comment: And this should be written as `if lst[0] in patterns: lst[0] = ''`.

Comment: @Tim: Submit that as an answer! I can't believe I came up with three other ways of doing that without the obvious one... ;-)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: that the way I would write it, but I did want to show (my interpretation) that he had this inside out...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Well if the OP has a wager on this, it could be written like this: `lst[0]='' if lst[0]==[x for x in patterns][0] else lst[0]`   :D

Answer (score 17):

The Python language has distinct concepts for expressions and statements.

Assignment is a statement even if the syntax sometimes tricks you into thinking it's an expression (e.g. `a=b=99` works but is a special syntax case and doesn't mean that the `b=99` is an expression like it is for example in C).

List comprehensions are instead expressions because they return a value, in a sense the loop they perform is an incident and the main point is the returned list.

A statement can contain expressions but an expression cannot contain statements.

That said however list item assigment to is internally converted to a method call (to allow creation of list-like objects) and method calls are expressions. Therefore you can **technically** use list item assignment in an expression:

```
[ lst.__setitem__(0, '') for pattern in start_pattern if lst[0] == pattern ]
```

This is however considered bad because it harms readability and how easy is to read source code is the *main focus* in the Python language. You should write instead for example...

```
for pattern in start_pattern:
    if lst[0] == pattern:
        lst[0] = ''
```

that by the way thanks to the `in` operator is equivalent to the even more readable

```
if lst[0] in start_pattern:
    lst[0] = ''
```

List comprehensions are used for their return value and they make a loop internally... If what you want is the loop then just write a loop... whoever will read the code trying to understand what it does would appreciate that a lot (and whoever includes yourself in a few weeks).

Answer (score 9):

In short: you don't. List comprehensions are for generating lists, not modifying existing lists. If you want to modify a list, use a for loop, as that's what they're for.

The Pythonic way to write that code would be something like:

```
for pattern in start_pattern:
    if lst[0] == pattern:
        lst[0] = ''
        #the following assumes that pattern will never be ''
        #if that's possible, you can ignore this bit
        break
```

However, if you really, really want to do assignment inside one, and don't mind every Python programmer who ever deals with your code hating it for all eternity, there are a few functions you can use:

- If the variable you want to assign to is a global, then you can do

  ```
      globals().update(var=value)
  ```
- If the variable you want to assign to is a mutable sequence or a map (such as a list or a dict)

  ```
      list.__setitem__(index, value)
  ```

Comment: The break is always valid. Even if there's a `''` in the data, it's only going to cause `lst[0]` to be reassigned the same value...

Comment: Unless lst is a mutable sequence type where element assignment has been overloaded to keep track of how many times a given value was assigned, or any other sort of non-standard behavior.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I would hope that's a very rare occurrence, though :-)

Comment: It's probably more common than you think, but less common than my comment assumes. The last several times I created a \_\_setitem__ method, they didn't do anything you wouldn't expect them to. However, relying on others' code to behave sensibly is not a very safe way to code.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the above answers there is no direct assignment possible in the list comprehension feature, but there is a hackable way to do it using the `exec` method to achieve the assignment.

Not just `assignments` we can pas any python expression in `exec` method to evaluate it.

In your case, it could be achieved by

```
  [ exec(f"lst[0] = ''") for pattern in start_pattern if lst[0] == pattern ]
```

If we have a list of objects and we want to assign a value to a specific attribute of the object on a specific condition then it could be like:

```
[ exec("p.age_status=child") for p in persons_obj_list if p.age <= 18 ]
```

Note: This will change the state of existing objects of a list and will not return the list of objects as it returns in normal use of list comprehention.

Answer (score 0):

If what you ment in the question is:

```
[ lst[0] = '' for lst in listOfLists if lst[0] == pattern ]
```

or for a list of patterns

```
[ lst[0] = '' for lst in listOfLists if lst[0] in patterns ]
```

This can actually be done easily

```
[ [''] + lst[1:] for lst in listOfLists if lst[0] == pattern ]
```

or for a list of patterns again

```
[[''] + lst[1:] for lst in listOfLists if lst[0] in patterns ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I believe that it is worth to present this scenario.

Suppose that you have a `list` of dictionaries, like this:

```
>>> fruits
[{'name': 'apple', 'quantity': 5}, {'name': 'banana', 'quantity': 4}]
```

With a normal list comprehension, you might find the object that you're looking for:

```
>>> [d for d in fruits if d['name'] == 'apple'] 
[{'name': 'apple', 'quantity': 5}]
```

As a result, you have a list with a single element, thanks to the `if` condition above.

Therefore, you can index the only element, accessing one of the dictionary keys and assigning a value:

```
>>> [d for d in fruits if d['name'] == 'apple'][0]['quantity'] += 1
```

Here the result:

```
>>> fruits
[{'name': 'apple', 'quantity': 6}, {'name': 'banana', 'quantity': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you, use a class instead of using variables to assign values.
When you use a class you can simply change the class value and then return the result.

I added one example that I did:

```
def foo():
class result:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = 0
        self.value = 0
        
    def change(self, key, value):
        self.key= key
        self.value= value
        return key

result_object= result()
class_result= [result_object.change(key, value) for key, value in temp_dict.items() if value > result_object.value][-1]
return class_result
```