# How can I use a function call result in a conditional list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I would like to turn this code into a list comprehension:

```
l = list()
for i in range(10):
    j = fun(i)
    if j:
        l.append(j)
```

Meaning that I'd like to add only truthy `fun()` result values to the list. Without the truthy check of that function call, the list comprehension would be:

```
l = [fun(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Adding a `if fun(i)` to the list comprehension would cause two evaluations of `fun()` per iteration (actually, not always it seems!), thus causing unintended side effects if `fun()` is not pure.

Can I capture the result of `fun(i)` and use it in that same comprehension, essentially adding the `if j`? (Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension))

Comment: `l = filter(None, map(fun, range(10)))` or `l = [x for x in (fun(i) for i in range(10)) if x]`

Comment: @falsetru: Your first statement returns an iterable `filter` object and not a list, whereas your second statement is a [filter idiom](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter) idiom and an actual list.

Comment: Yup, you need to wrap the first one with `list(...)` to get a list.

Comment: @falsetru: And that would result in a total of two iterations, unless all [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map), [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter) and [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-list) operate lazily (on demand).

Comment: `map`, `filter` operate lazily in Python 3.x (returns iterators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an inner generator in the list comp so you will look over the results of func

```
l = [j for j in (func(i) for i in range(10)) if j]
```

Comment: This is the [filter idiom](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter), but unlike the idiom which returns an iterable `filter` object, `l` is the requested list.

Answer (score 0):

Or combining two suggested solutions:

```
filter(None, (func(i) for i in range(10)))
```

Comment: This returns a `filter object` iterable, and not a list per se. In most cases, that might not matter though.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Much simpler:

```
[res for res in map(func, range(10)) if res]
```

Thanks for the hint to falstru.

### Old answer

Another option would to use a helper generator function:

```
def call_iter(func, iterable):
    for arg in iterable:
        yield func(arg)

[res for res in call_iter(func, range(10)) if res]
```

Comment: While this would work, it contradicts my obsession with one-liners and strive for maximum code density ;-)

Comment: Well, you can re-use the function. So putting it into a module `tools`, you just need one import to get your one-liner.

Comment: You don't need `call_iter`. You can reuse `map`.

Comment: @falsetru Pretty obvious. Sometimes things are too simple to recognize  them. Fixed.