# How to use += (Add AND) with List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to use the code below with list comprehension.

```
link = 'page={}&index={}'
index = 10
links = []
for page in range(2, 4):
    links.append(link.format(page, index))
    index += 10
```

I have tried many different ways and Googled as much as possible (maybe I am not searching for the correct terms?). I am still unable to figure it out. Below is one of the ways I tried but I get a `SyntaxError` error.

```
link = 'page={}&index={}'
index = 10
links = [link.format(link, index) for page in range(2, 4) index += 10]
```

This should be the output of the list comprehension:

```
['page=2&index=10', 'page=3&index=20']
```

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated it. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do assignments in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: Broadly speaking, A list comprehension can contain only expressions. `index += 10` is not an expression; it is a statement. So you can't put it inside a list comprehension. But even if you could do this, you should question whether you should. Not all code is improved by making it shorter.

Comment: @dfundako I edited the question to show my expected output. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin Oh ok, well that is fine too, not the end of the world if I can't do this. I just could not find anywhere that talked about doing this, etc... Thank you for that information.

Comment: @Kevin Great thing to remember when learning to code. Code will be written once, but read a hundred times. Make it easier to read and comprehend instead of saving a line or two of code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate): builtin function to increment the `index`:

```
>>> [link.format(page, i*10) for i, page in enumerate(range(2, 4), start=1)]
['page=2&index=10', 'page=3&index=20']
```

This will also work with any other iterable instead of just a `range(2, 4)`, e.g. a list of strings. Any such iterable can thus be augmented with a counter variable, like `index` in your example.

Comment: `enumerate` is overkill here, given that `i == page - 1`

Comment: @chepner Well, yes, but it is more generally applicable. Instead of `range(2, 4)`, you could have a range with steps, or just any iterable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use += statements (or any statement for that matter) in a list comprehension. In your case, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools
[link.format(page, index) for page, index in zip(range(2, 4), itertools.count(10, 10))]
```

Comment: yes what chepner said (almost) `[link.format(page, 10*(page-1)) for page in range(2, 4)]`

Comment: (I deleted my comment when I noticed I didn't have the relationship between page and link quite right; Chris got it, though.)

Comment: I am not sure if you want to make your comment into a answer so I can mark it right @Chris_Rands but this is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thank you for making such a simple and straight to the point answer.

Comment: @antfuentes87 I mean, they all do exactly the same thing... but it's your call I guess. I agree with @tobias_k though, `enumerate`/`itertools.count` are more versatile.

Comment: I do agree but I have to import itertools for yours to work and I do not have to with @Chris_Rands. Plus I had a very similar attempt when I was trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: @antfuentes87 I have to disagree with that. Don't ever be afraid of importing standard library modules, especially `itertools`, `collections` and `functools`. It will save you a lot of repetition. `itertools` is even a zero-cost import since it's used by python on startup. What about tobias_k's answer then? `enumerate` is a built in function.

Comment: If you are allergic to imports, you can do `[link.format(page, index) for page,index in zip(range(2,4),range(10,30,10))]` The key to this answer is `zip` with two increasing iterators...