# Update JSON element in Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

Trying to update/add to a JSON element using if/then statement in python list comprehension. The first part where I'm setting the JSON key 'first_seen' is failing. Any ideas why?

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B, %d, %Y")
[obj["last_seen"] = now for obj in ref_db if obj['user']==user else add_new(user, ext_source, source, first_seen, now)]
```

the error is:

```
[obj["last_seen"] = now for obj in ref_db if obj['user']==user else add_new(user, ext_source, source, first_seen, now)]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I understand from the error my syntax is wrong, but I can't figure out why it's wrong. Can you not use an equals (=) sign in a list comprehension?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's unclear what result you're expecting. Are you expecting `obj["last_seen"]` to be the resulting list?

Comment: You need a plain if/else statement inside a for loop instead of a list comprehension

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] that we can actually run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do assignments in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List-Comprehensions are for creating lists. You just want to use a for-loop:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B, %d, %Y")
for obj in ref_db:
    if obj['user'] == user:
        obj["last_seen"] = now
    else:
        add_new(user, ext_source, source, first_seen, now)
```