# I want to implement bubblesort using python list comprehension but it displays blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to implement bubblesort using python list comprehension but it displays blank. Tried using assignment operators to swap (`l[j]=l[j+1]`) but it throws an error as list comprehension does not support assignment

```py
l = [8, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 2]
newlist= [ [(l[j],l[j+1]),(l[j+1],l[j])] for i in range(1,len(l)-1) for j in range(0,len(l)-1) if l[j]>l[j+1] ]
```

Expected output is: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

But I am getting the output as `[]`.

Comment: When running your exact code the output is not `[]`.... Also, note that what you are getting in `newlist` is a list of lists of 2 tuples of 2 elements.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in a list comprehension? I can't imagine a world where that's the best approach.

Comment: The only reasonable approach to use bubblesort in a list comprehension is to write your bubblesort function separately, then call `sorted_list = [el for el in bubblesort(lst)]`

Comment: You can't use assignments in list comprehension. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension). The `if` in list comprehension is used for filtering, so you can't decide which pair to use: `(a,b)` or `(b,a)`. Try different approach.

Comment: Bubble sort is an *inplace* algorithm, whereas a list comprehension creates a *new* list. The two are fundamentally different approaches to handling data.

Answer (score 1):

This fails from a conceptual problem, which is that *every* filtered result must produce a value to include in the list.  Your list comprehension has no capability to store intermediate results -- it's doomed to failure.  You have to determine whether to emit a value, and which value to emit, given only the original list, `i`, and `j`.  That information does not exist with bubble-sort logic.

For instance, consider the first nested iteration.  You have this information at hand:

```
l = [8,1,3,5,4,6,7,2]
i = 1
j = 0
```

Given this, you must decide *right now* whether or not to put information into y our final list -- if so, which information to put there.  You cannot defer this to a second pass, because you have no temporary storage within the comprehension.

See the problem?