# Reassigning Numpy Array in For Comprehension

Tags: python, numpy

The following works:

```
data = np.ones(10*10).reshape(10,10)
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(i+1,10):
        data[i,j]=i*j
```

but the following is a syntax error:

```
data = np.ones(10*10).reshape(10,10)
[[ data[i,j] = i *j for j in range(i+1,10)] for i in range(9) ]
```

why?

Comment: Doing an assignment in a list comprehension is possible, but don't do it. There's no reason to allocate a giant 2d list just to throw it away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do assignments in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: Yes, that answers my question I think. It is a syntax error b/c you can't assign inside of list comprehension (i.e. - it is an error b/c it is an error)

Comment: Because list comprehensions are for expressing mapping/filtering operations, they aren't "single-line" for loops, they only accept expressions, and should be free of side-effects

Answer (score 0):

It is an error b/c you must use := to assign inside of list comprehension.

Comment: This won't work the same way either. That creates  a variable local to the loop, but you can't use assignment expressions to do item-assignment. Again, **list comprehensions are not designed to be used for side-effects**. They are for *mapping/filtering* operations on iterables **to create a list**

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use list comprehension for this, you may consider setting up a function.

```
def fu(i,j): data[i,j]=i*j      
[[fu(i,j) for j in range(i+1,10)] for i in range(9) ]
```