# Why does a list comprehension not work for updating a dictionary element using equals sign

Tags: python, python-3.x

Create a list of dictionaries, and then add a key:value pair to each dictionary using assignment:

```
my_list_of_dicts = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
x = [elem['c']=3 for elem in my_list_of_dicts]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = [elem['c']=3 for elem in my_list_of_dicts]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It works in a for loop, but not as a list comprehension.  Why is that?

```
for elem in my_list_of_dicts:
     elem['c']=3
 
my_list_of_dicts
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'c': 3}]
```

Comment: Because you're supposed to write that as a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do assignments in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: "It works in a for loop, but not as a list comprehension. Why is that?"—because `for` loops and list comprehensions are completely different things. A list comprehension isn't a loop. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: The above link doesn't answer why an assignment doesn't work in this case.  I'm not asking what a list comprehension is, I'm asking why assignment doesn't work for a dictionary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension doesn't support assignment in that way. Essentially what it does is create a new list by iterating through the old one. Look at the variable X. It's not being assigned anything because the variable assignment has no output.

Its generally a rule of thumb that every list comprehension can be written as a for-loop but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use assignement in a comprehension. Moreover, it is use usually a bad idea to use in-place modification in a comprehension.

You could do :

```py
>>> ld = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
>>> ld2 = [d.update({"c":3}) for d in ld]
```

But the content of `ld2` will not be your modified dictionary. it will be `[None, None, None]` and the variable `ld` had been edited in-place.

For in-place modification, use a `for`-loop.

```py
for my_dict in my_list_of_dict:
    my_dict.update({"c",3})
```