# How to use list comprehension to simplify code

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm solving a problem on codewars, and I needed to create a function that found the smallest number in an array. This is my code:

```
def find_smallest_int(arr):
    smallest_number = arr[0]
    for num in arr:
        if num < smallest_number: 
            smallest_number = num
        else:
            continue
    return smallest_number
```

My answer is correct. But I want to know how I could simplify my code using list comprehension (I'm fairly new to coding). This is what I tried, but I received an error:

```
def find_smallest_int(arr):
    smallest_number = arr[0]
    x = [smallest_number for num in arr if num < smallest_number , smallest_number = num]
```

What would be the correct way to use list comprehension in this case?

Comment: If you're not building a list, don't use a list comprehension.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension) thread to understand more about list comprehensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python you can just use the `min` function like so

```py
min(arr)
```

It'll return the smallest value in the list. If for some reason you don't want to do it this way, then write your own function like so

```py
def min_of_arr(nums):
  min_num = float('inf') # +infinity
  for num in nums:
    if num < min_num:
      min_num = num
  return min_num
```

P.S. List comprehension is used to get a list, not a single / atomic value.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are used to apply a simple function to an iterable and returns a list

```
list_ = [num**2 for num in numbers]
```

If a function is more complex, define the function (or use a `lambda` expression) and use `map()` to apply that function like

```
new_list = list(map(function, iterable))
```

or like

```
new_list = list(map(lambda num: num**2, num_list))
```