# Assignments in python list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am looking for a way to do assignments in a list comprehension. I would like to rewrite something like the following piece of code into a list comprehension.

I have this "costly" function:

```
import time
def f(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x + 1
```

And this loop:

```
l = []
for value in [1, 2, 3]:
    x = f(value)
    l.append(x + x)
```

I would like to rewrite this to a list comprehension:

```
l = [
     f(value) + f(fvalue)
     for value in [1, 2, 3]
]
```

But since calling `f(value)` is costly, I would like to minimize the number of calls (this following snippet doesn't run):

```
l = [
     (x = f(value))
     x + x
     for value in [1, 2, 3]
]
```

I've read about the assignment expression (`:=`) (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#changing-the-scope-rules-for-comprehensions) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: For the given example, does `l = [x*10 for x in [1, 2, 3]]` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do assignments in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: Does not work! `x, y = f(value)` requires `f` to return an iterable of 2 values, while your example only return a scalar.

Comment: After a second look,I think that you wanted `... return x, x+1`

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to nest multiple  list comprehension, like

```
l_new = [x * x * y for x, y in [f(value) for value in [1, 2, 3]]]
```

So `f()` should only be called once for each value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem for me would be that we introduce an extra loop which makes it a bit unreadable to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to fake it:

```
[x+x for value in [1, 2, 3] for x in [f(value)]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with a walrus operator. Note that you need Python 3.8 or later.

```
l = [x:=10 * value for value in [1, 2, 3]]
```

With one fast and slow function.

```
import time

def slow_function(a):
    time.sleep(1)
    return a + 1

def fast_function(b):
    return b + b  


l = [
     fast_function(x := slow_function(value))
     for value in [1, 2, 3]
]
```

The walrus operator can be skipped in both these examples, but perhaps the real problem would require it.

Comment: I think you don’t even need walrus assignment here, right?

Comment: Yeah for the original example I made this is true. I updated the post to demonstrate my problem more clearly.

Comment: In that case you could write one fast and one slow function, like this.

Comment: What would be the use of the walrus operator? Since `x` is not (re-)used

Comment: The original question looks like a simplification of a more complex real problem. Showing that a variable can be assigned inside a list comprehension might help someone solving an issue. I explain at the bottom that the walrus operator is not needed in this specific example.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to do it without creating extra functions?

Comment: You could write it as e.g. `l = [(x := f(value), x + x)[1] for value in [1, 2, 3]]`, if you're willing to create a tuple and take the second element of it inside the list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you, that's seems the best option. I think Python should add support for (multiple) assignments within list comprehensions, since using list comprehensions over for-loops is considered to be pythonic.