# Quickest and most concise way to generate a list of random, sorted integers

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of length n which contains n random unique integers, ordered by numerical value and with a difference of no more than 10 between any two elements.

I wrote this function:

```
import random
def make_list(n):
  list = []
  num = 0
  for i in range(30):
    num = num + random.randint(1,10)
    list.append(num)
  return(list)
```

It works but it seems verbose and I feel like there should be a better, more concise way using list comprehensions or other.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator expression to generate the intervals, then call [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to calculate the running sums.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> from random import randint

>>> list(accumulate(randint(1, 10) for _ in range(30)))
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 26, 31, 41, 49, 50, 58, 63, 72, 77, 81, 86, 88, 92, 101, 106, 109, 114, 116, 122, 123, 133, 143, 153, 159, 160]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random

def make_list(n):
  num = 0
  return [num := num + random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(n)]
```

You can use `:=` operator after Python3.8

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514656/17560347

Answer (score 1):

Using `islice` and `accumulate` from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module:

```py
import random
import itertools as it

def make_list(n):
    i = iter(lambda: random.randint(1, 10), None)
    return list(it.islice(it.accumulate(i), n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with the desired *n* passed as the `k` argument:

```
import random
from itertools import accumulate

print(list(accumulate(random.choices(range(1, 11), k=5))))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/VerifiablePleasingSolidstatedrive